# Mongoose: $sort case insensitive in many languages

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I have a query and i need to use `$sort` with case insensitive for many diferent languages. I read about [metadata sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#metadata-sort) but I can't understand how it works in my query or how can i make the sort works with case insensitive for many languages (utf-8)

**My query**

```
  let sort;
  if (sortDetailServices.field === "employee.name") {
    sort = {
      "employee.name":  sortDetailServices.status ? 1 : -1
    }
  }
     Schedule.aggregate([{
          '$match': findTerm
        },
        {
          '$facet': {
            'totalizer': [{
                '$group': {
                  '_id': '$service.id',
                  'count': {
                    '$sum': 1
                  },
                  'totalValue': {
                    '$sum': '$value'
                  },
                  'totalComission': {
                    '$sum': '$comissionValue'
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                '$group': {
                  '_id': null,
                  'storesCount': {
                    '$push': {
                      'store': '$_id',
                      'count': '$count'
                    }
                  },
                  'totalValue': {
                    '$sum': '$totalValue'
                  },
                  'totalServices': {
                    '$sum': '$count'
                  },
                  'totalComission': {
                    '$sum': '$totalComission'
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            'data': [{
                '$project': {
                  'employee.name': 1,
                  'value': 1,
                  'scheduleStart': 1,
                  'scheduleEnd': 1,
                  'comissionValue': 1,
                  'status': 1,
                  'paymentMethod': 1
                }
              },
              {
                '$sort': sort
              },
              {
                '$skip': req.body.limit * req.body.page
              },
              {
                '$limit': req.body.limit
              }
            ],
          }
        }
      ]
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: As of now mongodb have case insensitive indexes:

Update: This answer is out of date, 3.4 will have case insensitive indexes. Look to the JIRA for more information https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90

Unfortunately MongoDB does not yet have case insensitive indexes: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90 and the task has been pushed back.

This means the only way to sort case insensitive currently is to actually create a specific "lower cased" field, copying the value (lower cased of course) of the sort field in question and sorting on that instead.